# Is Opc UA Really Platform Independent?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

In the opc foundation [site](https://opcfoundation.org/about/opc-technologies/opc-ua/) says : "opc ua is platform independent."

I have looked the most used opc implementation products matrikon and kepserver.
When i look at these product documentation , both of require to work on windows based server.

I am stuck with that. Where is platform independency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a choice those products made.

Don't confuse OPC UA for a product that implements OPC UA.

[Ignition](https://inductiveautomation.com/ignition/modules/ignition-opc-ua), for example, is cross platform, including its built-in OPC UA server and drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Kevin Herrons Answer, there are various open source stacks available, which support different platforms.

E.g. open62541 (https://www.open62541.org) supports Linux, Windows, OS X, and a lot of embedded platforms.

A more complete list of OPC UA implementations can be found here: 
https://github.com/open62541/open62541/wiki/List-of-Open-Source-OPC-UA-Implementations

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of Course OPC UA is platform independent. Platform independency was the on major reason for moving from OPC classic to OPC UA.
here you are confusing with OPC UA standard and the product based on OPC UA.

Answer (score 0):

OPC UA is platform independent and one main reason is that it has a complete, extensive and not linked to any platform documentation ... and free available to all.

I wrote a year ago my own client for Android